# If statement with button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am having a problem where I would like to implement a button in WPF that will only run a certain message box  on the parameter that the user has selected the input from the combo box. The WPF is a basic covid 19 case checker and I was wondering why this code won't work.

```
namespace CovidWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
        public Country France;
        public Country Britain;
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Country Britain;
        
            countries.Add(Britain = new Country { Name = "Britan", Deaths = 70195, Cases = 2200000});
            countries.Add(France = new Country { Name = "France", Deaths = 62573, Cases = 2500000});

            countryList.ItemsSource = countries;
        }

        public void checkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (countryList.Name == "France")
            //{
                    MessageBox.Show("Cases", France.Cases.ToString());
            //}

            if (countryList.Name == "Britain")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cases", Britain.Cases.ToString());
            }
        }

        public class Country
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Cases { get; set; }
            public int Deaths { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *What* exactly isn't working? Please make this a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the selected item from your list like this

```
var selectedCountry = (Country)countryList.SelectedItem;

if (selectedCountry.Name == "Britain")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cases", Britain.Cases.ToString());
}

// etc
```